# Set segmentedController to NSArray of Dictionaries

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, nsarray, uisegmentedcontrol

I have this NSArray of dictionaries in view controller A, and then I send this segmentArray to viewController B when either btn 1 or btn 2 is pressed and then I want to set the segmented controller in view controller B to the corresponding btn that was pressed

```
NSArray *segmentArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@{@"title":firstBtnString, @"number":@"0"}, @{@"title":twoBtnString, @"number":@"1"}, nil];
```

Then to set the segmented controller I do this

```
 NSMutableArray *segmentArrayTitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *segmentArrayNumber = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < segmentArray.count; i++) {
    [segmentArrayTitles addObject:segmentArray[i][@"title"]];
    NSInteger value =  [segmentArray[i] integerValue];
    [segmentArrayNumber addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:value]];

}


UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:segmentArrayTitles];
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(20, 9, 280, 29);
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(selectMeal:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.smallView addSubview:segmentedControl];
//Here I want to set the segmented controller to the correspoding value depending on which btn was pressed
```

How would I go about doing this?

So to reiterate I want to set the segmented controller to the corseting btn that was pressed.

Thanks for the help in advance.

**EDIT**

So on ViewControllerA I have 2 buttons in a custom tableview cell we will call them Btn 1 and Btn 2. When either button is pressed it goes to ViewController B. In view controller B I want to set the segmented controller to the title of the buttons in view controller A, and set it selected to the button that was pushed.

Does that make more sense?

Thanks

Comment: I guess I don't understand.  If that's what you want to do, why don't you just do it?

Comment: @HotLicks Im not sure how or I would just do it, I have the buttons both call the same method currently, is it possible to do with one method or will I need a separate method for each button.

Comment: The method only needs to know which button was pressed, in order to know what legends to use on the segments.  Several ways to do that.  (This might be a good situation for a sort of delegate.)

Comment: @HotLicks Right how would I let the method know which button was pressed? what is sort of delegate?

Comment: You could always pass it a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, based on your edit, here is a new answer:

Give view controller A an NSInteger property called `index` and this code:

```
- (IBAction)buttonAAction:(id)sender {
    [self setIndex:0];
}

- (IBAction)buttonBAction:(id)sender {
    [self setIndex:1];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    ChildViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
    [controller setSegment:self.index];
}
```

View controller B gets an IBOutlet to its segmented control and this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:self.segment];
}
```

In the storyboard, set up your two buttons in view controller A, and the segmented control in view controller B. Then make two segues: one from button A to view controller B, and one from button B to view controller B.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is quite what Im looking I have update my question, I try to explain it better